# expain following code snippet

Tags: c++

please explain me following code snippet

```
void tsfa_sol::calculate_cost(const pro_base *pb)
{
    const tsfa_pro &tsfap = *(tsfa_pro*)pb; //I can't understand this line
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: It's a typecast followed by a dereference. It means the same as `tsfa_pro* tpb = (tsfa_pro*) pb; const tsfa_pro &tsfap = *tpb;`.

Comment: You should think about precising what you can't understand in this piece of code if you want anyone to help you. The left hand term seems pretty clear, but we just don't know if it is for you for example

Comment: the left hand term is easy but the righ hand I see two pointers (sorry because I am a .NET dev. And the pointer is very hard to understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it casts `pb` in `tsfa_pro *` then it dereference it
in another words, `tsfap` is a reference to what pointed by `pb`, using a C-style cast to convert `pb` from `pro_base` to `tsfa_pro`.

Answer (score 0):

(tsfa_pro*)pb = C style casting of pointer "pb" which originally of type pro_base

*(star)(tsfa_pro*)pb = content of pointer "pb" casted to type tsfa_pro

const tsfa_pro &tsfap = constant reference of type "tsfa_pro"

So, its assigning the reference(tsfap), the content of pointer (pb) type-casted to type (tsfa_pro)

Hope this helps